# Aspose Workbook not created for excel template containing images

Tags: java, aspose, aspose-cells

In my java application i am trying to create a Workbook from a template. Here is a code snippet to do that,

```
InputStream inStream=new FileInputStream(file);        
Workbook workbook = new Workbook(inStream);
```

When the template is blank or contains plain text, it is converted to Workbook but when template contains png or other charts exception occurs as:

> com.aspose.cells.CellsException: Invalid sectionId of Header Footer
>   image

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

We need your template file to evaluate your issue properly. Please post your issue with template Excel file in the [Aspose.Cells forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.cells-product-family/19/showforum.aspx) there, we will check it soon.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: My template contains, some pngs at the header and footer section, I got the solution by upgrading the aspose.cells version to 9.0.0